# Embeddable scripting language with in-memory runtime

Tags: scripting-language

I am looking for an embeddable scripting runtime that can operate entirely in memory and not require to store libraries on disk. It should match the following criteria:

- Be able to interact with Windows API and/or COM in some fashion;
- Could load runtime and supporting libraries entirely in memory (no RAMDISK);
- portability is a plus, but just Windows could do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be pretty close to what you want:

http://luaplus.org/

http://luaservice.luaforge.net/

http://luaforge.net/projects/jaslatrix/